# Use button inside controller

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to search users in a panel with ajax. But along with that, I also want to edit the selected user.

I have created the button inside the controller to achieve this but the button isn't working.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function searchTeacher(Request $request){
if($request->ajax()){
    $output = '';
    $query = $request->get('query');
    if($query != '')
    {
        $data = DB::table('users')->where('name', $query)->get();
    }else{
        $data = DB::table('users')->get();
    }
    $total_row = $data->count();
    if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->teacherId.'</td>
            <td>'.$row->subject.'</td>
            <td> <button href={{route(update-teacher-view), '.$row->id.'}}> Edit</button> </td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = '
        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    $data = array(
        'table_data'  => $output,
        'total_data'  => $total_row
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

Here is the ajax for search method-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    fetch_customer_data();

    function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
    {
        console.log(query)
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('search-teacher') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
                $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
            }
        })
    }

    $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
        var query = $(this).val();
        fetch_customer_data(query);
    });
});
```

Here is my html-

```
<section class="panel">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="team-list chat-list-side info border-less-list">
                    <th>Teacher Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Teacher Id</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
```

A solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a wrong string interpolation? Should be like this:

```
<?php
$output .= '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->teacherId.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->subject.'</td>
    <td> <button href='.route('update-teacher-view', $row->id).'> Edit</button> </td>
    </tr>
    ';
```

Also instead of `echo`-ing, just return the value, it will be automatically converted to JSON response:

```
// echo json_encode($data); // Change this line to below
return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Have tested this before and again tested it but still the button isn't working.

Comment: In your controller, how if you `return` the `$data` instead of `echo`-ing its JSON representation? BTW, I updated my answer.

Comment: Used return but still having same issue:

`$('tbody').append('
<tr><td>'+data[0].name+'</td>
<td>'+data[0].email+'</td>
<td>'+data[0].teacherId+'</td>
<td>'+data[0].subject+'</td>
<td><button href="route(admin,'+ data[0].id+')'+'">edit<button></td></tr>');`

Answer (score 0):

Render the blade file with the data this is the best solution.

In controller

```
return View::make('ajaxFilter',compact('data'))->render();
```

On **ajaxFilter.blade.php**

```
<section class="panel">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="team-list chat-list-side info border-less-list">
            <th>Teacher Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Teacher Id</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if($data->count() > 0)
                @foreach($data as $row)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->teacherId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->subject }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ route('update-teacher-view',$row->id) }}">Edit</a> //button design
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                No data Found
            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

On ajax response, you can append HTML data something like that

```
$('#div_or_section_id').html(data);
```

Comment: In this: `View::make('ajaxFilter',compact('data'))->render();` ajaxFilter is the name of my view right? Have used this its returning error undefined variable Data.

Comment: Yes, the ajaxFilter (ajaxFilter.blade.php) is the file name and you can pass the variables in compact .
that will render the HTML with your data

Comment: Yup, have done that before but still its giving error, undefined variable Data.

Comment: return `View::make('ajaxFilter',compact('data'))->render();`
 before this line `$total_row = $data->count();` it should be work

Comment: yup tried it may b m missing some thing, its giving error: undefined variable Data

Comment: where did you get error in blade file or controller?